# Is it possible to get a timestamp from the GitLab GraphQL or REST API for when a user's account was created (progress in description)?

Tags: rest, python-requests, graphql, gitlab, gitlab-api

How can I get a timestamp for when a user's account was created?

I had a look at the API docs. On the GraphQL API I didn't see anything.
On the REST API, I see this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#for-user but a user seems to be a user in context of a project, which is fine but then I have a couple of probably basic questions

1. I'm not sure if 'created_at' really shows when the user's account was created (as desired), or if it shows something in the context of the project? There is no description next to 'created_at'.
2. What is the URL that I would make the request to? It looks to me like the id is within a project rather than a GitLab wide id... so the URL would include the project (or maybe some kind of group?) number, but the reference linked above doesn't seem to clearly show the full URL, just says `GET /users/:id`, so in that case I'm not sure what else should be in the URL after `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/`.
   EDIT: Or can the author id found here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr be used as a GitLab wide user id and used to get the author age? In which case `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/:id` would work. I'll test this on `curl` now.

Thanks for reading, Milan

Comment: For 1) I just hit the API for my user, and it matches with when I created my account. You can view it in the UI on a users profile page (ie, https://gitlab.com/orediggerco)


For 2), `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/users/:id"`

Answer (score 0):

`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/<id>` did contain createdAt, which was when the user's account was created. I'm not sure why I thought that the user id was in a project context, I think I decided that because the examples on their website used user_ids of 1 and 2.